# How to convert Python date format '%B - %Y' back to '%Y-%m-%d'?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm working with a data frame containing dates in the '%B - %Y' format and need to convert them back to a datetime '%Y-%m-%d' format in order to make date calculations.

For example, I'd like to convert `old_date = 'July - 2016'` to a new date variable `new_date = '2016-07-15'`, where it's OK to use an arbitrary value (here the 15th of the month) for the day.

My first pass at the problem, which returned `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`:

```
from datetime import datetime
df['new_date'] = datetime.strptime(str(df['old_date']), '%Y-%m-15')
```

Comment: Just parse with `datetime.strptime('July - 2016', '%B - %Y')` and the day will default to 1

Comment: @yatu So something like this ought to work: `df['new_date'] = datetime.strptime(df['old_date'], '%B - %Y')`. I'm still getting an error `TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Series`.

Comment: Well your example was a string. For vectorized datetime operations on Series, use the datetime accessor `dt`. so `My_datetime_Series.dt.strptime...`

Comment: @yatu Got it - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit ::

I didn't do any benchmark, but just so you know, casting your column as date, doing... `df['your_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['your_column'])` will convert any date you have to an ISO format. See below the second example.

The second example should be way faster though. :)

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    'A' : ['July - 2019', 'June - 2020'],
    'B' : [1, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df, end='\n\n')
#              A  B
# 0  July - 2019  1
# 1  June - 2020  2

day_to_put = 15
df['A'] = df['A'].apply( lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%B - %Y')\
                                           .replace(day=day_to_put)\
                                           .strftime('%Y-%m-%d') )

print(df)
#            A  B
#0  2019-07-15  1
#1  2020-06-15  2
```

### Second example

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    'A' : ['July - 2019', 'June - 2020'],
    'B' : [1, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df, end='\n\n')
#              A  B
# 0  July - 2019  1
# 1  June - 2020  2

df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])

print(df)
#             A  B
# 0  2019-07-01  1
# 1  2020-06-01  2
```

Comment: @RobertF I added the functionality you wanted, to be able to pick a day instead of having the first day everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Not neat but it should work:

```
months = {'January': '1',
          'Febuary': '2',
          'March': '3',
          'April': '4',
          'May': '5',
          'June': '6',
          'July': '7',
          'August': '8',
          'September': '9',
          'October': '10',
          'November': '11',
          'December': '12'}

def convert(old_date):
    pts = old_date.split(' - ')
    return '-'.join((pts[1], months[pts[0]], '15'))
```

---

Explanation:

- `months = {'January': '1', ...` create a month name → number dictionary
- `pts = old_date.split(' - ')` split the input into the form `['July', '2016']`
- `(pts[1], months[pts[0]], '15')` a tuple, containing:

  - `pts[1]` the second value (year)
  - `months[pts[0]]` looks up the first value (month name) in the afore mentioned dictionary
  - `15` the day, change as appropriate
- `'-'.join(...)` concatenates the values of above tuple with a `-` between them <sup>*1</sup>

---

<sub><sup>*1</sup>See [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) documentary of the `String.join` method.</sub>

Comment: See my answer, just casting the column using `pd.to_datetime()` solves the problem as pandas guesses your date format and converts it automatically to an ISO format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following syntax :

```
df['new_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['old_date'],format='%b-%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```